# XSLT 1.0 Group By and Sum to compare

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following XML

```html
<AllTransactions>
 <TaxSummaries>
  <TaxSummary>
   <TypeId>1</TypeId>
   <Amount>100.00</Amount>
  </TaxSummary>
  <TaxSummary>
   <TypeId>1</TypeId>
   <Amount>200.00</Amount>
  </TaxSummary>
  <TaxSummary>
   <TypeId>2</TypeId>
   <Amount>300.00</Amount>
  </TaxSummary>
  <TaxSummary>
   <TypeId>2</TypeId>
   <Amount>400.00</Amount>
  </TaxSummary>
 </TaxSummaries>
</AllTransactions>
<CurrentTransaction>
 <Taxes>
  <Tax>
   <TypeId>1</TypeId>
   <Amount>25.00</Amount>
  </Tax>
  <Tax>
   <TypeId>1</TypeId>
   <Amount>25.00</Amount>
  </Tax>
  <Tax>
   <TypeId>2</TypeId>
   <Amount>50.00</Amount>
  </Tax>
  <Tax>
   <TypeId>2</TypeId>
   <Amount>50.00</Amount>
  </Tax>
 <Taxes>
</CurrentTransaction>
```

1. Collection of TaxSummary within \AllTransaction\TaxSummaries and
2. Collection of Tax within CurrentTansaction\Taxes

I need to compare the sum of Amount by TypeId in \AllTransaction\TaxSummaries against the sum of Amount by TypeId in CurrentTansaction\Taxes using XSLT.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: Is there an any built in group by functions that I can make use of? I don't want to loop each record to group and sum the values before I can compare. I was looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best accomplished using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Read the article and study some of the many examples posted here on SO.